# Error installation ALM Quality Center 12.60 with oracle database

Tags: schema, privileges, alm, hp-quality-center

I need to understand why can I not install this software.
I have installed and followed all steps in Windows 7 and Oracle 12.1, and I get 
this error about admin schema credentials, after I connect with database, during the installation, and using user SYSTEM in oracle with all privileges, 
any idea?, 
thanks for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your User qcsiteadmin_db does not have all the necessary permissions.
We us a dedicated user for accessing the database. The user has been created and got permissions before the installation. Have a look at the installation manual, page 94.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)